# How can I find out correct div, class, span when scraping a html page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, simple-html-dom

I am new in Web scraping technology. I tried to implement Web scraping after reading various web tutorials like [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-only-step-by-step-guide-youll-need-to-build-a-web-scraper-with-python-e79066bd895a) and [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/amazon-web-scraping-using-beautifulsoup#comments). Those articles are about amazon web scraping and Netflix web scraping. There are lots of other tutorials on Imdb, Rotten Tomatoes and others. Those tutorials give me overview which attributes need to take like `class attributes, div tags` etc. Different websites have different methods to take those tags. However those tags are the fundamental elements of web scraping. When I follow those tutorials I can implement those codes but when I try to parse a different website other than the mentioned one I failed. Recently, I tried the code block over *priceline*. But I just messed up with so many html codes.

My code for price line

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
url= 'https://www.priceline.com/relax/in/3000005381/from/20210301/to/20210319/rooms/1?vrid=8848a774a531423bde3ed4ff3486f8bb'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

name=[]
hotel_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='Box-sc-8h3cds-0.Flex-sc-1ydst80-0.iNmVhl')
for container in hotel_div:
   name = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'Box-sc-8h3cds-0 Flex-sc-1ydst80-0 BadgeRow__BadgeContainer-fofgl-0 kmpPcP SummaryHeader__BadgeRowWithMB-m5g1dm-0 dQyPUf SummaryHeader__BadgeRowWithMB-m5g1dm-0 dQyPUf'})
   n = name.find_all('img', alt=True)
   row={}
   if name is not None:
     #print(n[0]['alt'])
     row['Name'] = n[0]['alt']
   else:
      row['Name'] = "unknown-product"
print(name)
```

It returns an empty array.

Can any one suggest any tutorial or web blogs which help me to identify the correct html tags for any website?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Your question is off-topic. See the [help/on-topic] for what is on-topic.

Comment: Websites use different `js & css` so your class is almost always going to be different. `js & css` uses the `class` field for styling. It is unlikely you can use the same `class` across different sites. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. You could probably turn this into a decent question, but you'll probably find by following the advice that you'll work out how to solve your problem, or formulate a better question which has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Each web developer will choose to name their classes and tags differently.

To check how a new site is structured you can right click on what you want to scrape and then click on inspect and a tab should appear where you can find the tag, class name, etc

Comment: Yeah I find those tag, class name. However one tab say price has more than one div and class name. The structure is like <div>class = '....' ahref='url' <div> src= '...' </div></div>   like that. I was confused which one I needed to include which one should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

(***UPDATED***) Now it works:

```
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import requests
    from selenium import webdriver
    url = 'https://www.priceline.com/relax/in/3000005381/from/20210301/to/20210319/rooms/1?vrid=04bab06455d612983ec0c76e621d7c48'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = soup(html,"lxml")
    container = soup.find('a',{'class':'Link-sc-16qjtx7-0 TitleLink__TitleLinkText-vs18lp-0 jtrNVn'}).text
    print(container)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJK0c.png

Comment: My problem is not with identifying the url.  In the name field I was confused with the lots of class name. Name means the name of the hotel. When I tried to inspect the corresponding element for name I got lots of classes. I failed to understand which one is correct for scraping.

Comment: Ok I will try. So in that case there is nothing to do with BeautifulSoup. right?